# Получение текста событий из Event Log'a в Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Имеется не плохой пример от Microsoft по работе с Event Log, но проблема в том что текста самих событий он не выдаёт. Как можно получить текст событий?

```
    HANDLE h;
    EVENTLOGRECORD *pevlr;
    BYTE bBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD dwRead, dwNeeded, cRecords, dwThisRecord;
    WCHAR LogName[15];

    // Open the event log.
    printf("\nInput Log Name you want to Read (Application, Security, \
System):\n");
    scanf("%s", LogName);

    h = OpenEventLog( NULL,    // use local computer
             LogName);   // source name
    if (h == NULL)
        printf("\n Could not open the Application event log\n");
                //ErrorExit("Could not open the Application event log.");

    pevlr = (EVENTLOGRECORD *) &bBuffer;

    // Get the record number of the oldest event log record.

    GetOldestEventLogRecord(h, &dwThisRecord);

    // Opening the event log positions the file pointer for this
    // handle at the beginning of the log. Read the event log records
    // sequentially until the last record has been read.

    while (ReadEventLog(h,                // event log handle
                EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ |  // reads forward
                EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ, // sequential read
                0,            // ignored for sequential reads
                pevlr,        // pointer to buffer
                BUFFER_SIZE,  // size of buffer
                &dwRead,      // number of bytes read
                &dwNeeded))   // bytes in next record
    {
        while (dwRead > 0)
        {
            // Print the record number, event identifier, type,
            // and source name.

            printf("%02d  Event ID: 0x%08X ",
                dwThisRecord++, pevlr->EventID);
            printf("EventType: %d Source: %s\n",
                pevlr->EventType, (LPSTR) ((LPBYTE) pevlr +
                sizeof(EVENTLOGRECORD)));

            dwRead -= pevlr->Length;
            pevlr = (EVENTLOGRECORD *)
                ((LPBYTE) pevlr + pevlr->Length);
        }

        pevlr = (EVENTLOGRECORD *) &bBuffer;
    }

    CloseEventLog(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

Сам текст событий лога хранится в ресурсных локализованных dll.
Такой порядок получения текста:

1. Находим в реестре ресурсную dll:

   ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\ pevlr->Source \ EventMessageFile
   ```
2. Загружаем ресурсную dll:

   ```
   HANDLE hResources = LoadLibrary
   ```
3. Получаем текст сообщения по pevlr->EventID:

   ```
   FormatMessage( 
           dwFormatFlags,
           hResources,
           (DWORD)pevlr->EventID, 
           ... )
   ```
4. Также поступаем для получения текста категории:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\ pevlr->Source \ CategoryMessageFile
```