# Вывод логов действий с файлами

Tags: c++, windows, файлы, логирование

Где найти файл лога Win с информацией о, например, кол-ве удалённых папок или файлов? Ну, не само количество, а, допустим, просто инфу о том, какие действия делал пользователь. Очень нужно, хочу выводить это в консоль.

Comment: А файловые операции венда логирует вообще?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Если попросить, то да: https://superuser.com/questions/402792/can-i-log-file-operations-create-modify-delete-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Операции с файлами по умолчанию в Windows не заносятся в журнал событий (так как при этом бы туда сыпалось слишком много неинформативных записей). Их логирование можно включить, как описано [здесь](https://superuser.com/questions/402792/can-i-log-file-operations-create-modify-delete-in-windows). Тогда информация о работе с файлами будет попадать в журнал аудита, откуда ее можно [считать с помощью WinAPI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612571/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-event-loga-%D0%B2-windows).

Однако, для NTFS-дисков кое-какую информацию об операциях с файлами можно получить из USN-журнала тома, без необходимости в изменении настроек системы. Недостаток способа в том, что записей там много, их считывание идет медленно, а отфильтровать их можно только последовательным проходом всего журнала до необходимого времени. Код для вывода первых 50 записей из USN-журнала (для запуска требуются права администратора):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinIoCtl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_LEN 4096

//вывод содержимого журнала USN для тома
void PrintJournal(TCHAR* volume,UINT max_count){
   HANDLE hVol;
   CHAR Buffer[BUF_LEN];

   USN_JOURNAL_DATA JournalData;
   READ_USN_JOURNAL_DATA ReadData = {0, 0xFFFFFFFF, FALSE, 0, 0};
   PUSN_RECORD UsnRecord; 
   SYSTEMTIME st;
   int c=0;

   DWORD dwBytes;
   DWORD dwRetBytes;

   hVol = CreateFile( volume, 
               GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
               FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
               NULL,
               OPEN_EXISTING,
               0,
               NULL);

   if( hVol == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
   {
      printf("CreateFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      goto End;
   }

   if( !DeviceIoControl( hVol, 
          FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, 
          NULL,
          0,
          &JournalData,
          sizeof(JournalData),
          &dwBytes,
          NULL) )
   {
      printf( "Query journal failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      goto End;
   }

   ReadData.UsnJournalID = JournalData.UsnJournalID;

   printf( "Journal ID: 0x%I64x\n", JournalData.UsnJournalID );
   printf( "FirstUsn: 0x%I64x\n\n", JournalData.FirstUsn );

   while(true)
   {
      memset( Buffer, 0, BUF_LEN );

      if( !DeviceIoControl( hVol, 
            FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL, 
            &ReadData,
            sizeof(ReadData),
            &Buffer,
            BUF_LEN,
            &dwBytes,
            NULL) )
      {
         printf( "Read journal failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
         goto End;
      }

      dwRetBytes = dwBytes - sizeof(USN);

      // Find the first record
      UsnRecord = (PUSN_RECORD)(((PUCHAR)Buffer) + sizeof(USN));  

      printf( "****************************************\n");

      // This loop could go on for a long time, given the current buffer size.
      while( dwRetBytes > 0 )
      {
          //получаем время записи...
         if(FileTimeToSystemTime((FILETIME*)&(UsnRecord->TimeStamp),&st)==false){
             printf( "\nfailed to get time\n");
             goto End;
         }      

         //выводим данные
         printf( "%4d.%02d.%02d %2d:%02d\n",(int)st.wYear,(int)st.wMonth,(int)st.wDay,(int)st.wHour,(int)st.wMinute); //время записи
         printf("Reference number: 0x%I64x\n", UsnRecord->FileReferenceNumber ); //ID файла
         printf("File name: %.*S\n", UsnRecord->FileNameLength/2, UsnRecord->FileName ); //имя файла         

         printf( "Reason: 0x%x", UsnRecord->Reason ); //причина изменений
         if( (UsnRecord->Reason & USN_REASON_FILE_DELETE)>0)printf( " (File deleted)" );    
         if( (UsnRecord->Reason & USN_REASON_FILE_CREATE)>0)printf( " (File created)" );
         if( (UsnRecord->Reason & USN_REASON_DATA_OVERWRITE)>0)printf( " (Data overwrite)" );
         if( (UsnRecord->Reason & USN_REASON_DATA_EXTEND)>0)printf( " (Data extend)" );
         printf( "\n\n" );       
         c++;
         if(c>=max_count) goto End;//если прочитано указанное количество записей, выходим

         dwRetBytes -= UsnRecord->RecordLength;

         // Find the next record
         UsnRecord = (PUSN_RECORD)(((PCHAR)UsnRecord) + 
                  UsnRecord->RecordLength); 
      }
      // Update starting USN for next call
      ReadData.StartUsn = *(USN *)&Buffer; 
   }

   End:
   CloseHandle(hVol);  
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");    

    PrintJournal(TEXT("\\\\.\\c:"),50);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
Journal ID: 0x1d213cf6845e9c2
FirstUsn: 0x160b40000

****************************************
2018.03.25  6:01
Reference number: 0xb80000000256ed
File name: GetStateWorker20180325.log
Reason: 0x2 (Data extend)

2018.03.25  6:02
Reference number: 0x21f0000000356fb
File name: cache.dat
Reason: 0x80000200 (File deleted)

2018.03.25  6:02
Reference number: 0x78000000038ae2
File name: asw-8d99b330-1115-4672-8629-c820c1720c18.tmp
Reason: 0x1103 (File created) (Data overwrite) (Data extend)

2018.03.25  6:02
Reference number: 0x78000000038ae2
File name: cache.dat
Reason: 0x2103 (File created) (Data overwrite) (Data extend)

2018.03.25  6:02
Reference number: 0x78000000038ae2
File name: cache.dat
Reason: 0xa103 (File created) (Data overwrite) (Data extend)

2018.03.25  6:02
Reference number: 0x78000000038ae2
File name: cache.dat
Reason: 0x8000a103 (File created) (Data overwrite) (Data extend)
```

[MSDN - Walking a Buffer of Change Journal Records](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365736(v=vs.85).aspx)