# Подскажите можно ли посмотреть историю действий над файлом / видео / фото, который хранится на компьютере?

Tags: windows

Подскажите можно ли посмотреть историю действий над файлом / видео / фото, который хранится на компьютере?

Какие манипуляции проводили над файлом, копировали, открывали и т.д.

Операционная система windows 7 professional

Comment: Если включен аудит файловых операций, или какая третья программа этим занимается (скажем, антивирус) - да, иначе нет. И историю не действий, а просто доступа. Действий - только в логе программы, которая "действовала".

Comment: Вот здесь есть кое-что: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/805933/240512